# How to regenerate all views automatically after doing changes to the Models they based on

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC app using EF. The models, views and controllers are fine and working well.

I have to change my View Models, so the Views are now based on these changed models.

I don't want to manually change all 50 views one by one. I'm asking if there is a way to re/generate the existing Views automatically, based on the changed models declared in the View without deleting them and creating them again.

Thanks in advance.